# setrlimit on another process

Tags: linux, unix, resources, posix, limit

I know I can use [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) to limit the resources my program can use, but if my program launches another process, how can I set corresponding limits on that other process?

N.. Yes, I could lower my own (hard) limits and then fork, but being unprivileged, would not be able to put my own limits back up again. This is not a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You `fork()` **first** and then call `setrlimit()` before `exec()`.

Comment: Indeed this kind of thing is exactly why `fork()` and `exec()` are separate system calls; so you can change the child's environment in between (without affecting the parent).